# New variable for each user input in a loop

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, input, user-input

I am currently working on a program that takes a user input of the number of students in a class, then, (in a while loop), takes a user input of a student number and their average grade, then, after calculation, prints the highest mark, lowest mark, and average mark of the class.

This is what I have done so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ClassMarks {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number of students in class: ");
        int students = input.nextInt();
        int x = students;
        while (x > 0) {
            System.out.println("Enter student number: ");
            double studentNumber = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter student grade: ");
            double studentGrade = input.nextDouble();
            x = x - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I am looking for a way to get the program to create a new variable for me that stores each new user input student grade inside the while loop.
ex) studentGrade1, studentGrade2, studentGrade3 ...

Comment: Store them in a List.

Comment: List is not necessary for the specified requirements.

Comment: @radoh +1 actually, storing is not necessary. The OP can also keep the highest mark, the lowest mark and the sum of the marks.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle yup, I've just added such answer/suggestion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before the `while` loop, create variables highest/lowest grades

```
double highestGrade = Double.MIN_VALUE, lowestGrade = Double.MAX_VALUE;
double gradeSum = 0;
```

Then as you loop through the values, adjust the variables appropriately, e.g.

```
if (studentGrade > highestGrade)
    highestGrade = studentGrade;
if (studentGrade < lowestGrade)
    lowestGrade = studentGrade;
gradeSum += studentGrade;
```

And then after the loop finishes, get the average like this

```
double averageGrade = gradeSum / students;
```

Comment: `highestGrade = Math.max(studentGrade, highestGrade)` would be nicer :) Same for `lowestGrade`.

Comment: Nicer, true, but it would mean rewriting the variable on every loop, even when the value doesn't change. Hmmm, dilemma... :)

Comment: Ohhhhh... You're right, a list isn't required. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about using a List.

```
List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>()
```

and in while loop

create a student update its fields then add it to the list

```
Student myNewStudent = new Student();
// update fields 

students.add(myNewStudent);
```

To iterate the list you can use a for loop.

```
for (Student s : students) { 
    // Get student info
}
```

Adapting this into your code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ClassMarks {
// Create an inner class Student

    public static class Student {

        public double studentNumber;
        public double studentGrade;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number of students in class: ");
        int students = input.nextInt();
        int x = students;

        // Create a list to hold your students
        List<Student> studentsList = new ArrayList<>();

        while (x > 0) {
            Student myNewStudent = new Student();
            System.out.println("Enter student number: ");
            myNewStudent.studentNumber = input.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter student grade: ");
            myNewStudent.studentGrade = input.nextDouble();

            // update fields 
            studentsList.add(myNewStudent);

            x = x - 1;
        }

        // Loop your student List
        for (Student s : studentsList) {
            // Get student info
            System.out.println("Student number is: "+s.studentNumber+" grade is : "+s.studentGrade);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I then refer back to the variables when I need to do the calculations for average grade for example?

Comment: all the students will be in "students" list. you can refer them as for example students.get(0)

Comment: @ScopeY `for (Student s : students) { (do something here) }`